Inspect accessor functions in Firefox dev console
In Firefox, when I log an object that has accessor functions (getters/setters) to the developer console, I need to expand __accessor__ > store > _values_ > entries to inspect the values:

In Edge (or Chrome), I can see these properties right under the object, and inspect values by clicking on (...). This is of course much more convenient:

Is there a way to do the same in Firefox?

Which Firefox version?

@Destroy666 Any recent version really. I'm at 131 right now, but if nightly or beta has it than that's fine too
